# How can I have two Arduino Uno's communicate wirelessly?

Tags: wireless

I'm an art student, using arduino in an Electronic Arts Class.  I have already created a skateboard speedometer, using a Hall Effect Sensor and a magnet embedded in one of my skateboards wheels.  I've attached a speaker to the arduino that plays a tone, with the pitch depending on the RPM's of the wheel.  (the faster the board is going, the higher pitch the tone being played is).  Currently the speaker is attached to the skateboard and wired directly to the arduino.  My goal is to have a speaker with an arduino wirelessly connected to the arduino on the skateboard.  The arduino on the skateboard record's the RPM's and then wirelessly send that information to the second arduino to play the tone through the speaker.  Is this possible? what hardware would yo recommend? I've been looking at the Bluetooth HC-05 but I'm not sure this will work.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: The nRF24L01+ modules are a popular choice for this type of thing, and will be much more direct to work with than anything Bluetooth.  You could also consider using a short range analog radio to send audio generated at the source with a stock headphone/speaker audio receiver, but may have trouble finding a quiet channel in an urban area.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So two of the nRF24L01+ modules connected to both arduino's should do the trick?

Comment: Probably, at least if misoperation/non-operation has no serious consequences.  For a point of comparison, a significant minority of the little quadcopter toys fly around via signals sent through compatible transceivers.

Comment: If you do buy the modules, make sure you download the library either through the IDE or from github.com/TMRh20/RF24. That way you'll have a library that has active development and is almost bug free.

Answer (score 1):

ESP8266 is also a good choice. these little guys are really useful and give you a Wi-Fi connection between your Arduino boards.

Also, the cost of one ESP8266 is about $3.. super cheap!

[image]